# Java FXML Login form the parameters are not send from the database to go to next form

Tags: java, fxml

[a view from my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6JVC.png)

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable {
    Librarian l1=new Librarian();
    @FXML
    private TextField username;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField password;
    @FXML 
    private Button loginButton;
    @FXML
    private Label status;
    @FXML
    private Label loginStatus; 
    @FXML
    public void LibrarianLogin(ActionEvent event) {
    try {

        if(this.l1.isLogin(this.username.getText(), this.password.getText())) {
            Stage stage = (Stage) this.loginButton.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
            adminLogin();
        }
        else {
            loginStatus.setText("Invalid");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception locaException) {

    }       
}

public void adminLogin()
{
    try {
        Stage adminstage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader adminLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        Pane adminroot = (Pane)adminLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Librarian/admin.fxml").openStream());
        AdminController adminController = (AdminController)adminLoader.getController();
        Scene scene =new Scene(adminroot);
        adminstage.setScene(scene);
        adminstage.setTitle("Admin Dashboard");
        adminstage.show();        
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    if(this.l1.isDatabaseConnected()){
        this.status.setText("Connected to Database");
    }
    else{
        this.status.setText("Not Connected");
    }
}

Connection connection;
public Librarian(){
    try {
        this.connection=dbConnection.getConnection();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(this.connection == null){
        System.exit(1);    
    }    
}

public boolean isDatabaseConnected(){       
    return this.connection != null;
}

public boolean isLogin(String username,String id)throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement pr= null;
    ResultSet rs= null;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Librarian where username = ? and password = ?";

    try {
        pr=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        pr.setString(1,username);
        pr.setString(2, id);
        rs = pr.executeQuery();      
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        return false;
    }  
    finally {
        pr.close();
        rs.close();
    }
}
    return false;
}
```

when ever i retrieve data from database to text box in login form nothing happens when i click the login button. Even when i enter wrong credentials the label to set login invalid doesn't work.

I made different packages:

- package for logging in
- package for database
- package for admins after logging in

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is the connection to database established?

Comment: Yes. I created it in sqlite @rengas

Comment: can you locaException.printStackTrace() in your catch block to know whether there is any exception thrown?

Comment: I got a null pointer exception
at Login.Libraraian.isLogin
@Rengas

Comment: now i have fixed that null pointer exception
but when i enter the username and password as in my sqlite database
i got the invalid message which i made as an indication for me to see if the username and password are wrong! 
@Rengas

Comment: You are always returning false from isLogin method? You need to check the resultset and return true.And also you need to do something  with your exception.